# how to add a ITEM node to the following GROUP using JSON in WinRT?

Tags: json, windows-runtime

```
{"Groups":[
  {
    "UniqueId": "Group-1",
    "Title": "Group Title: 1",
    "Subtitle": "Group subtitle: 1",
    "ImagePath": "Assets/DarkGray.png",
    "Description" : "Group Description goes here",
    "Items":
    [
      {
        "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-1",
        "Title": "Item Title: 1",
        "Subtitle": "Item Subtitle: 1",
        "ImagePath": "Assets/LightGray.png",

      },
      {
        "UniqueId": "Group-1-Item-2",
        "Title": "Item Title: 2",
        "Subtitle": "Item Subtitle: 2",
        "ImagePath": "Assets/DarkGray.png",
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Check out [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Store App, you can use "[Windows.Data.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.aspx)".